# Is there any way I can print String array without using for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Is there any function in java like toString() to print a String array?

This is a silly question but I want to know if there is any other way than writing a for loop.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to join an array of strings into one string?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
String[] array = { "a", "b", "c" };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: When I think string joining I normally think String joining with delimiters, except in very specific situations.

Comment: What if we have an array of strings, and want simple output; like: `String[] array = {"John", "Mahta", "Sara"}`, and we want this output without bracket and commas: `John Mahta Sara`?

Answer (score 12):

With [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/),

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.join(anArray,","));
```

Comment: Or since Java 8 `String.join(",", anArray)` so there is no need for external libraries.

Answer (score 5):

There is the [`Arrays.toString()`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) method, which will convert an array to a string representation of its contents. Then you can pass that string to `System.out.println` or whatever you're using to print it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a bit more control over the string representation, [Google Collections Joiner](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) to the rescue!

```
String[] myArray = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
String joined = Joiner.on(" + ").join(myArray);
// =>  "a + b + c"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
System.out.printf(String fmtString, Object ... args)
```

Where you specify the format of the output using some custom java markup (this is the only part you need to learn). The second parameter is the object, in your case, the array of strings.

More information:
[Using Java's Printf Method](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/UsingJavasprintfMethod.htm)

Answer (score 1):

With [op4j](http://www.op4j.org/),

```
String[] myArray = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};

System.out.println(Op.on(myArray).toList().get());
```

Comment: That's really a nice library!

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] values= { ... }
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(values));
```

Comment: What if we have an array of strings, and want simple output; like: `String[] array = {"John", "Mahta", "Sara"}`, and we want this output without bracket and commas: `John Mahta Sara`?